# What online Italian wine stores ship to USA (South-West)?

Tags: wine, buying

What online Italian wine stores ship internationally? I know [Vino75](https://www.vino75.com/) does not.

Comment: If you let us know you're location, someone from that region may be able to help with an Italian wine distributor in the area.

Comment: @Bee Southwest United States

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image: Italian Wine Selection]

The [**Italian Wine Selection**](https://italianwineselection.com/) will ship internationally. They seem to have a large selection. Caveat: Some countries at any one time may or may not be deliverable due to particular domestic rules and laws of the country being shipped to.

> We are in the wonderful city of Sorrento, you can come and visit us in our 3 restaurants, where in addition to drink the wines of Italian Wine Selection, you can enjoy specialties of our land revisited by our Chef. - [Enoteca on line - Italian Wine Selection](https://www.italianwineselection.com/en/our-history.html)